# Maven: Dependency to pom module is not include submodules from it

Tags: java, maven, module

Project have next structure:

```
root
|
+--Module 1
|  |
|  +--Submodule_1
|  |
|  +--Submodule_2
|  |
|  +--Submodule_N
|
+--Module 2
```

`Module 2` depend on `Module 1` and expected access to classes from submodules 1..N

`Root` pom.xml:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>root</artifactId>
    <version>master</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>Module_1</module>
        <module>Module_2</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

`Module 1` pom.xml:

```
<project>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>root</artifactId>
        <version>master</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>Module_1</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>Submodule_1</module>
        <module>Submodule_2</module>
        ...
        <module>Submodule_N</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

`Submodule_N` pom.xml:

```
<project>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>Module_1</artifactId>
        <version>master</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>Submodule_N</artifactId>
</project>
```

`Module 2` pom.xml:

```
<project>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>root</artifactId>
        <version>master</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>Module_2</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>Module_1</artifactId>
            <version>master</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

So this configuration fail with error `package com.example.submodule_n.x.y does not exist`.

If add dependency from `module 1` to `submodule_n` than package will be found but maven fail with error  `...is referencing itself`.

One working case if add dependency from `module 2` to `submodule_n`. But expected way when `module 2` will have only one dependency to `module 1` for include all submodules from `module 1`.

It is can do gradle, but I don't have any ideas how it implement using maven.

Answer (score 0):

> One working case if add dependency from module 2 to submodule_n. **But expected way when module 2 will have only one dependency to module 1 for include all submodules from module 1**

That is your expectations that are actually not valid.

The purpose of configuration like:

> ```xml
>    <modules>
>        <module>Submodule_1</module>
>        <module>Submodule_2</module>
>        ...
>        <module>Submodule_N</module>
>    </modules>
> ```

is to somehow organise project structure, it have nothing in common with dependencies between java libraries (though, it affects build lifecycle), moreover, the configuration like:

> ```xml
>    <dependencies>
>        <dependency>
>            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
>            <artifactId>Module_1</artifactId>
>            <version>master</version>
>            <scope>compile</scope>
>        </dependency>
>    </dependencies>
> ```

in general does not make sense because library may not depend on pom - actually that just tells maven to build `Module_2` after `Module_1`.

Summarising statements above: if `Module_2` depends on `Submodule_N` you must explicitly define that dependency in pom.xml